# PHP funciona en XAMPP pero no en mi host

Tags: php

Actualmente estoy trabajando con PHP un mini sistema con SINGLE HTML DOM, en mi localhost funciona perfecto con XAMPP(Ultima version) y al pasarlo a mis hosting (version PHP 7+) me salta el sigiente error en error_log:

```
[12-Aug-2019 14:12:09 America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/adiccion/public_html/es/saf/simple_html_dom.php on line 82
[12-Aug-2019 14:12:09 America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://www.marcadores.com/): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 82
[12-Aug-2019 14:12:09 America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in /home/public_html/index.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/public_html/index.php on line 8

(linea 8)    foreach($html->find('span.name') as $element) {
      array_push($spans_name, $element->innertext);
    }
```

La linea 8 es la del error. las otras son warnings que son errores del single_html_dom.php

Comment: El primer `warning` te dice exactamente porque no funciona `file_get_contents`, la directiva esta `allow_url_fopen=0`, es decir, esta desabilitada la posibilidad de abrir `urls`. Necesitas ir al `php.ini` y activarla. El tercer `fatal error` resulta de lo anterior no anduvo y por lo tanto `$html` es igual a `false`

Comment: Donde edito eso, porque en xampp funciona. el problema surgio al pasarlo al hosting

Comment: Y eso depende de tu `Hosting` y la capacidad de personalización del mismo. Deberías contactar al equipo soporte del mismo

Comment: No es problema de mi codigo. Si no del hosting?

Comment: Depende del punto de vista. Lo cierto es que aparentemente tu `hosting` tiene una configuración para `PHP` diferente a la de tu entorno de local (`XAMPP`).